# Where can I find an up-to-date hyphenation library?

Tags: hyphenation

I am an English-American speaker. I am new to hyphenation. I've been testing it recently. I am asking whether or where LaTeX maintains an up-to-date hyphenation dictionary/hyphenation patterns similar to other word processors. Is there a package or LaTeX engine that does this for you?

Comment: Probably haven't been updated in 40 years but it's not like languages change that quickly anyway.

Comment: it depends on the language. The experimental german patterns for example are updated regularly. For US-english there is a maintained exception list https://ctan.org/pkg/hyphenex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TeX hyphenation patterns for American English have worked pretty well for about 40 years, that is, from the release of TeX82 (or TeX version 2).

There is, however, quite an extensive list of hyphenation exceptions mainly for words in scientific fields.

Be sure to

```
\input{ushyphex}
```

if you want to load those exceptions. The list is actively maintained by the TeX Users Group; new suggestions can be reported to

```
tex-hyphen@tug.org
```

Note that some typesetting frameworks such as InDesign, use the same algorithm and the same patterns as TeX.

Comment: You might want to suggest that, if an exception is found, it can be reported to tex-hyphen@tug.org ; more information at https://tug.org/tex-hyphen/